# Array summation conditioned on maximum and uniques

Tags: list-manipulation

Given three arrays, for example

```
s={1,3,2,3,1,2,3,2,1}
r={4,2,6,5,4,6,2,1,3}
f={1,3,9,1,8,4,4,8,2}
```

I'm trying to output four summary arrays

1. The uniques of s
2. For each unique of s, the maximum of r with that s
3. The number of entries which have that (s,r) combination
4. The sum of f's of those corresponding entries

For example

```
o1={1,2,3}
o2={4,6,5}
o3={2,2,1}
o4={9,13,1}
```

(For s=1 the maximum r values was 4, of which there were two of them, and the sum of the corresponding f values is 1+8=9)

I've been doing a loop across the uniques using Position function, etc. Slow and not optimized using the Mathematica notation. The arrays can be millions in length.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{o1, o2, o3, o4} = Transpose @  Values @ KeySort @
  GroupBy[Transpose[{s, r, f}], First, 
     Apply[{First @ #, First @ #2, Length @ #2, Total @ #3} &] @* 
       Transpose @* MaximalBy[#[[2]] &]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 6, 5}, {2, 2, 1}, {9, 13, 1}}
> ```